# Atomic List - is this collection threadsafe and fast?

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections

I am trying to figure out the best way to have a collection that I will be able to iterate over, add items and remove items all from different threads concurrently.  Performance is critical for the iteration component, but Items will not be added to and removed very often - so add/remove performance is slightly less important.

Here is what I came up with:

```
public class AtomicList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly object Locker = new object();
    private List<T> InternalCollection = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T Value)
    {
        lock (Locker)
        {
            List<T> Update = new List<T>(InternalCollection);
            Update.Add(Value);
            InternalCollection = Update;
        }
    }

    public void Remove(T Value)
    {
        lock (Locker)
        {
            List<T> Update = new List<T>(InternalCollection);
            Update.Remove(Value);
            InternalCollection = Update;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return InternalCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Are there any drawbacks to doing it like this? Would there be any circumstance when this would not be threadsafe/iterable like I described above?

Also - is there any performance cost for using a foreach and IEnumerable?  Would it be better if I accessed the InternalCollection directly and did a for statement over it?

Comment: better suits to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why not use an existing concurrent list like `ConcurrentBag`?

Comment: But can you iterate over the concurrent bag and add/remove simultaneously?

Comment: @L.B - just out of curiosity - what is the purview of StackOverflow now that you guys have the CodeReview site?

Comment: @William - Code review is for taking a working piece of code and analyzing it for best practices. Stack Overflow is for solving programming related problems.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't call the Add and Remove method concurrently, you don't need the `lock`s, since you're only ever reading from the list referenced by the `InternalCollection` field. Use the [Interlocked.Exchange Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337971.aspx) to replace the old list with the new list in a thread-safe way:

```
public class AtomicList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private List<T> internalCollection = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T vlue)
    {
        List<T> update = new List<T>(internalCollection);
        update.Add(value);
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref internalCollection, update);
    }

    public bool Remove(T value)
    {
        List<T> update = new List<T>(internalCollection);
        bool removed = update.Remove(value);
        if (removed) Interlocked.Exchange(ref internalCollection, update);
        return removed;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        ...
```

Comment: This does not prevent modification to the backing `List<T>` during enumeration.  `List<T>` is not thread safe in that regard.

Comment: The backing List<T> is not modified.

Comment: Just noticed that... any previously fetched enumerator still refers to the old backing instance.

Comment: This is a bit copy heavy but it should work great for small lists or rarely modified lists.

Comment: Right - that's the point. My idea was that since the List can never actually be modified (because when a new component is added or removed, it is replaced by a new instance), it will be able to be iterated over. This obviously means that any iteration will be working with the old version of this list though... are there any pre-existing method for accomplishing this type of thing?

Comment: @William - Hopefully a stale copy of the list isn't a problem. I can imagine it might be in time dependent situations (Like a service that only runs at certain times).

Comment: I believe the thread-safe collections of .NET all optimise for add/remove at the cost of enumeration being slow. If you want to optimise for enumeration at the cost of add/remove being slow, you have to roll you own collection. It might be a good idea to use a profiler/Stopwatch to compare the performance of the code in my answer with the thread-safe .NET collections.

Comment: Another issue is when 2 threads try to modify the collection concurently ... there is a chance that modification of one will not reflected in final collection (thread 2 will override modification of thread one)

Comment: @NicolaeDascalu When you say "modify" do you mean adding and removing elements?  I thought that the Interlocked.Exchange took care of any threading issues?

Comment: No, my version only works if there are no two threads adding and/or removing elements at the same time. If there are such threads, you need the `lock`s. (So my code is not fully equivalent to the original code.)

Comment: @William The issue is before the Interlocked.Exchange ... For example both treads run Add method, both creates clone of original list and modified, so next step on interlocked call only one modification is propagated. Solution we should make Add and Remave Synchronized or add lock ...

Comment: ah okay cool - so if i make it a blocking add/remove with an object locker (like I did originally), then it should work correctly in all situations?

Comment: @William yes, this is all about.